# Return strucure from function

Tags: c++

hi have this 2 pieces of code in my program:

```
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR PE::GetImportedLibInfo(LPSTR libName )
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER doshdr = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)EntryPoint;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS nthdr = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)doshdr + doshdr->e_lfanew);
    DWORD tmp =nthdr->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
    DWORD Rva = RvaToOffset((DWORD)tmp);
    if(Rva != -1)
    {
        Rva += EntryPoint; 
        PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR iid =(PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(DWORD)Rva;

        while(iid->Characteristics)
        {
            char* dll = (char*)((DWORD_PTR)RvaToOffset(iid->Name)+ EntryPoint);
            DWORD res=lstrcmp((LPCSTR)dll,(LPCSTR)libName);
            if(res == 0)
            {
                return iid;
            }
            iid ++;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}


VOID FillLibInfo(PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR iiD)
{
    if(iiD != NULL)
    {
        char* buff[20];
        wsprintf((LPSTR)&buff,"%08lX",(DWORD)iiD->OriginalFirstThunk);
        SetDlgItemText(hImpDlg,IDC_EDIT1,(LPCSTR)&buff);
        wsprintf((LPSTR)&buff,"%08lX",(DWORD)iiD->TimeDateStamp);
        SetDlgItemText(hImpDlg,IDC_EDIT2,(LPCSTR)&buff);
        wsprintf((LPSTR)&buff,"%08lX",(DWORD)iiD->ForwarderChain);
        SetDlgItemText(hImpDlg,IDC_EDIT3,(LPCSTR)&buff);
        wsprintf((LPSTR)&buff,"%08lX",(DWORD)iiD->FirstThunk);
        SetDlgItemText(hImpDlg,IDC_EDIT4,(LPCSTR)&buff);
    }
}
```

And then i use it so:

```
FillLibInfo(GetImportedLibInfo("MyLibName"));
```

what append is that my textboxes don't actualize text until i pass mouse hover them

and after a couple of calls to `GetImportedLibInfo()` the program crash.
i think that is something with stack corrupted...

can someone give me a hint?

@Edit:

Class PE defenition:

```
class PE
{
private:
DWORD ptrImgDosHeader;
DWORD RvaToOffset(DWORD Rva);
DWORD RvaToMemory(DWORD Rva);

public:
DWORD EntryPoint;
PE(DWORD ptrMemory);
~PE();
VOID EnumSections(BOOL (*ptrCallBack)(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
VOID EnumImports(BOOL (*ptrCallBack)(LPSTR,DWORD),DWORD);
VOID EnumImportedFunctionsFromLib(LPSTR,BOOL (*ptrCallBack)(LPSTR,LPSTR));
VOID EnumExportedFunctions(BOOL (*ptrCallBack)(LPSTR,LPSTR,LPSTR));
WORD GetPeType();
DWORD ValidatePE();
DWORD ValidateNtHeader();
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR GetImportedLibInfo(LPSTR lib);
};
```

Comment: C++ or C? You gotta decide...

Comment: @Griwes Far as I can see, he put one `::` operator into an otherwise C program.

Comment: Where are the `PE` objects allocated? Are they in a container such as `vector` or `list`? What is the definition of `class PE`?

Comment: For the crashes you should use a debugger! It will help you pinpoint the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to see what might be the cause.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I didn't look into it, I asked about tags. As a general rule, I refuse to read questions that are marked with both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] and don't seem interesting. This question doesn't, and code in it should be trashed immediately...

Comment: @Potatoswatter, the PE is a class and i use other methods from it with success so the object is initialized correctly...

Comment: @BrunoFrade That is *not* a logical argument. Nor was I referring to initialization.

Comment: @Potatoswatter i have added the class definition to my post, and i don't understand your question: Where are the PE objects allocated?

Comment: @BrunoFrade How do you create an object of class `PE`? Stack, heap, `static`, inside a container, ???

Comment: @Potatoswatter the object is created inside a WM_KEYUP of a listview, wen the arrow keys is pressed i get the item text(library name), create the object of type PE and call FillLibInfo with selected item text, the problem is subsequent creation of the object? how can i create this object once and use it across my application?

Answer (score 2):

You're writing a string to a char pointer array, not a char array, so you're writing to some random pointer (whatever the uninitialised array's first element is pointing to, which will be unallocated memory).

Try using `char buff[20]` instead of `char* buff[20]`, then use `wsprintf( buff, ... )` and `SetDlgItemText( ..., buff )`.

Comment: ...but be careful of buffer overrun; wsprintf doesn't check buffer length!

Comment: … or just use C++ a la `std::stringstream`…

Comment: Good catch. I also notice that he's using wsprintf() into that buffer, and then passing the buffer to SetDlgItemText() as a C string. I think it won't cause the crash here, but is that likely to be another problem?

Comment: `wsprintf` should work fine with C strings. It's not the wide-string version `swprintf` (nice one there, C function name designers!), but effectively just an alternative to `sprintf`.

Comment: hi Nick Shaw, i have changed the code as you said but stays the same,
this isn't nothing to do with the function "PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR PE::GetImportedLibInfo(LPSTR libName )" ?